# axis and dimension mismatch between numpy and tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

In numpy
`A = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])` we see here shape is `(2, 3, 3)`
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfgyR.png)

here in numpy shape is `(z-axis, y-axis, x-axis)`

But in tensorflow let we have an image of 227,227 with 3 channels(R,G,B) , so my tensor is of shape `(227,227,3)` and
then I apply:-
`Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size = 11, strides =4, padding = 'valid')`

and we get following shape:-  [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2NzH.png)

then we apply BatchNormalization:-

```
BatchNormalization(axis = 3)
```

this BatchNormalization will be along feature axis(i.e third axis) of the input matrix and we have input matrix of shape `(55,55,96)` from 'screenshot2',

**So to sum up, in tensorflow we see that a 3 dimensional tensor shape is in following order- `(heigth, width, no_of_channels)` i.e. `(y_axis, x_axis, z_axis)`,
But in numpy we have `(z_axis, y_axis, x_axis)`**

This sometimes becomes confusing to link this two ideas,
Please tell me if I am missing some important concept ,if not then how to deal with this dimension mismatch.

Comment: `(z-axis, y-axis, x-axis)` that's not how numpy docs puts it.  That's your way of describing the display, not numpy's.

Comment: Yes, I know there have been two convension of the dimension structure: (Z,Y,X) and (Y,X,Z) .. but you said 'that's not how numpy docs puts it' ,  then how numpy puts it?   what is the actual shape of numpy and tensors under the hood.

Comment: `numpy` numbers the dimensions, `axis=0` etc.  One way to describe your (2,3,3) array is 2 planes, 3 rows, 3 columns.  But if it's a color image it could be a 2x3 image with 3 color channels.  Names are application specific.

Comment: So, If I have a 30*30 RGB image and I want store it in a numpy array X and then pass it to Conv2D layer , what should be the structure of X     (30,30,3) or (3,30,30) ?        ....I know X should be a numpy array of shape (30,30,3) but doesn't this makes the shape deform like now we have 30 , 2D planes of shape (30,3) ....

Comment: But I guess it is just the convension of how we visualize a numpy array and everything works fine in backend , right?

Comment: No, how the array displays has little to do with how the data is stored.  You may need to read some numpy basics.  An array has a 1d data-buffer with all the values. It also has a `shape`, `strides`, and `dtype` that together determine how those values are processed.  An array can be 2d, 1d, 3d, 10d, or even 0d.

Comment: If the data in your array represents an image, you'd display it with `imshow` or other image tool.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html.  It expects 2d arrays (M,N) or 3d (M,N,3) or (M,N,4).